# Getting Error while Overriding Password Reset Template Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

hello i have just started working on laravel 5.3 and soon came across this issue. Unlike 5.2, where we have hardcoded emails or some custom packages, here we are restricted to a single template.

So first of all i have updated the user model to include

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Then i have a notification file called ResetPasswordNotification and inside i have a

```
 public function toMail()
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line([
                'You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.',
                'Click the button below to reset your password:',
            ])
            ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
```

But i want to include a custom email template views and send data to these views  like how we did earlier. Now to impliment the old style in the new laravel we have to adopt it like this.

```
 return (new MailMessage)
            ->view('emails.templates.layout5')
            ->data([
                'pageTitle' => 'Password Reset',
                'logo' => $logo,
                'topMenu' => 'TOP MENU',
                'mainTitle' => 'Verify email to',
                'subTitle' => 'Reset Your Password',
                'image' => 'largeimg.png',
                'content' => $content,
            ]);
```

**But when i do this, i get an error**

```
ErrorException in MailChannel.php line 44:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: Can you try setting a variable, say $data, equal to the inner array. Then rewrite as ->view(...)->with($data);   ?

Comment: do you have the password reset migration migrated? do you have the  Constructor receiving the user object?  have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#after-resetting-passwords

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob i did try using an array so i have different array items like $data['pageTitle'] = 'Password Reset';  and then i pass them as ->with($data); And i have also changed all the template variables to $data['variable']. But it looks like the data array is not passed over to the template.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob, I think the data is not passed over because in the email template if i check for isset($data['pageTitle']) this condition becomes false